# Upgrading to Oracle JDBC thin driver results in SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle9i, weblogic-10.x

In Upgrading to Oracle JDBC thin driver results in `SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection` (WebLogic Server 10.0, oracle version ) we are getting the error listed below.

We did follow Oracle's advice to

1. change the global timeout in weblogic, i.e. For the JDBC Connection Pools set the `XASetTransactionTimeout` to `true` and `XATransactionTimeout` to zero
   When this parameter is set to zero, the XAResource Session Timeout will be set to the global transaction timeout.
   Hence the time out on the WLS needs to be modified
2. If the issue still remains it can be avoided by setting `KeepXAConnTillTxComplete="true"`.

   Database Product Version : Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options JServer Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production
   JDBC Driver Name : Oracle JDBC driver
   JDBC Driver Version : 11.1.0.7.0-Production

We know one option is not to use an XA connection, but in our case that is not a possibility. We defenitly need to use XA connections.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_PROTO start() failed on resource 'serviceDataSource': XAER_PROTO : Routine was invoked in an inproper context
oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1101)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:237)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.VendorXAResource.start(VendorXAResource.java:50)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.start(DataSource.java:696)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.start(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1183)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1116)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:275)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:508)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:435)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1407)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1331)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:426)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.connect(DataSource.java:383)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:339)
```

Comment: Just checking, but you're sure you need XA connections? They're a lot more complex than normal JDBC, don't use them unless you really need to.

Comment: Yes we defenitly need to use XA connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so consultation from Oracle we decided to upgrade the driver to the latest driver available. This seems to have solved the issue.